# Можно ли упростить запрос

Tags: mysql, mysqli, kohana

Доброе время суток,
Есть 3 табл.: «*roles*» (табл. c ролями), «*roles_user*» (связывающая табл), «*user*» (табл. c пользователями)
Мне нужно вытянуть всех пользователей с их ролями
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал запрос, который это делает:

```
SELECT tt1.*
       ,roles.name 
FROM ( 
       SELECT MAX(role_id) as maxrol
              ,tt.* 
       FROM (
              SELECT users.*
                     ,roles_users.role_id 
              FROM users 
              left join roles_users 
                   on roles_users.user_id = users.id 
              left join roles 
                   on roles_users.role_id = roles.id
            ) tt
       GROUP BY tt.id 
       ORDER BY tt.role_id
      ) tt1
left join roles 
     on tt1.maxrol = roles.id
```

Результат запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**:
Можно ли его упростить?

Comment: покажите результат который должен быть на выходе, по текущему вопросу не понятно. А приведенный запрос еще больше запутывает, ощущение что вы пытаетесь получить какую то максимальную роль для пользователя.

Comment: Вот результат, который должен быть: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iga5xrqoo8h8wkd/Result%20request.png?dl=0

Comment: Зачем вам выбирать максисмальный идентификатор роли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так (не проверял, ибо создавать таблицы по картинкам тяжело):

```
 SELECT U.*, R.name
   FROM users U
   LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT user_id, MAX(role_id) as maxrol
          FROM roles_users
         GROUP BY user_id
      ) RU ON RU.user_id=U.id
   LEFT JOIN roles R ON R.id=RU.maxrol
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так написать:

```
SELECT 
  u.username,
  r.name
FROM
  users u,
  roles r,
  users_roles l
WHERE l.user_id = u.id
  AND l.role_id = r.id;
```

Comment: Чуть чуть не так. При вашем запросе выдается список пользователей, но пользователь с "id": 22, 23, 24 - выдается с 2-мя ролями и "admin" и "login". А у меня "admin" привалирует на "login", то мне нужно отображать только юзеров с основными ролями (или "admin" "login"). Так что я ваш запрос чуть дописал:            SELECT tt1.*, roles.name FROM 
(SELECT MAX(role_id) as maxrol, tt.* FROM (SELECT u.*, l.role_id FROM users u, roles r, roles_users l WHERE l.user_id = u.id AND l.role_id = r.id ORDER BY u.id) tt GROUP BY tt.id ORDER BY tt.role_id) tt1 LEFT JOIN roles on tt1.maxrol = roles.id

Comment: @Konstantin78 Но у вас в вопросе сказано "_вытянуть всех пользователей с их ролями_" это подразумевает, что надо получить все роли всех пользователей. Ни слова о том, что что то над чем то привуалирует в вопросе нет. Поправьте вопрос, что бы он точно выражал суть

Comment: извиняюсь не корректно поставил вопрос

Comment: @Konstantin78 Я просто думаю что можно еще упростить, там где вы max получаете таблица users например вообще не нужна, группировать можно по пользователю из user_roles

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю